signoz-zookeeper-1 chown: changing ownership of '/bitnami/zookeeper/data': Permission denied
I am setting up Signoz in my local machine(Mac - Intel chipset). I am using docker-cli to setup the Signoz.
Initially it was giving the error permission denied for signoz-clickhouse. This issue is resolved.
Now I am getting the same permission denied for signoz-zookeeper-1
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.60 
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.60 Welcome to the Bitnami zookeeper container
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.60 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.61 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.61 
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.61 INFO  ==> ** Starting ZooKeeper setup **
hotrod                 | 2024-06-25T16:03:30.648Z       INFO    frontend/server.go:96   HTTP request received   {"service": "frontend", "trace_id": "29585290fab71791", "span_id": "29585290fab71791", "method": "GET", "url": "/dispatch?customer=123&nonse=0.6308392664170006"}
signoz-zookeeper-1     | zookeeper 16:03:30.64 WARN  ==> You have set the environment variable ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
hotrod                 | 2024-06-25T16:03:30.650Z       INFO    customer/client.go:54   Getting customer        {"service": "frontend", "component": "customer_client", "trace_id": "29585290fab71791", "span_id": "29585290fab71791", "customer_id": "123"}
hotrod                 | http://0.0.0.0:8081/customer?customer=123
hotrod                 | 2024-06-25T16:03:30.652Z       INFO    customer/server.go:67   HTTP request received   {"service": "customer", "trace_id": "29585290fab71791", "span_id": "13b1a5690dcc28de", "method": "GET", "url": "/customer?customer=123"}
hotrod                 | 2024-06-25T16:03:30.652Z       INFO    customer/database.go:73 Loading customer        {"service": "customer", "component": "mysql", "trace_id": "29585290fab71791", "span_id": "13b1a5690dcc28de", "customer_id": "123"}
signoz-zookeeper-1     | chown: changing ownership of '/bitnami/zookeeper/data': Permission denied
signoz-zookeeper-1 exited with code 1

I am able to resolve the  signoz-clickhouse issue by giving the permissions for usr/var/clickhouse directory. The below command worked for me
chmod 755 /var/lib/clickhouse/
Any suggestions to solve permission issue for signoz-zookeeper-1

to solve signoz-clickhouse permission denied issue, I used below command.
sudo chmod +wrx /var/lib/clickhouse/

This issue happens when the ownership/permission of the data directory used by clickhouse/zookeeper in SigNoz is not permissive enough.
This can happen for multiple reasons. Most common being switching between root and non-root user.
You can resolve this by updating ownership/permission for the data/clickhouse and data/zookeeper-1 directories.
Make sure to bring down the cluster before updating these and bring back up.
cd ~/signoz # change directory to repo root
make down-signoz # bring down SigNoz cluster

# try updating ownership to the container user UID (usually 1000 or 1001)
chown -R 1000:1000 deploy/docker/clickhouse-setup/data/zookeeper-1

# try updating permissions of the data directory recursively
chmod -R 755 deploy/docker/clickhouse-setup/data/zookeeper-1

# bring SigNoz cluster back up
make run-signoz


The ~/signoz/deploy folder had fulll 755 access. But still I am getting the permission denied error.
vinukumar@colima:/Users/vinukumar/experiments/signoz$ ls -lt.
total 244.
drwxr-xr-x 1 vinukumar dialout    224 Jun 26 09:11 deploy.

did you updating it recursively with -R flag?
